Error with the wheelchart latex package in org-mode
I am attempting to use the wheelchart latex package from within org-mode. A very minimal org-mode document throws an error on export when the \usepackage{wheelchart} line is added.
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{wheelchart}
** Text                    
This is text.

My org-latex-pdf-process is latexmk -e '$max_repeat = 10' -shell-escape --diagnostics -gg -g -rules -xelatex %f.
The generated tex is:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\author{Name}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Text}
\label{sec:orgb3e812}
This is text.
\end{document}

The error thrown is:
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/wheelchart/wheelchart.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeys@code #1\pgfeov ->\tl_gset:Ne 
                                      \g__wheelchart_name_tl {#1}
l.2338   }
          
? 
! Emergency stop.
\pgfkeys@code #1\pgfeov ->\tl_gset:Ne 
                                      \g__wheelchart_name_tl {#1}
l.2338   }

I got to this point after starting trying to make examples from the wheelchart package work.

The error happened while processing wheelchart.sty: note that (in contrast to tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex) there is an opening paren before it but no closing paren.

After noticing that a pdf file was produced with the default org-latex-pdf-process... (Answer totaly re-written, the pdf had errors.)
My error was in my latex setup. See matexmatix's explanation in this TEX stackexchange post.
My expl3 package (part of the LaTeX3 kernel distribution) is not up to date. The workaround given fixes the issue, when running from the tex file. For org-mode I think I will have to update my texlive instalation.

You always need the --output-directory=-%o option in the command(s) of your org-latex-pdf-process, but otherwise you should be able to use the one in your question.

As a workaround, you can create your own mywheelchart.sty file, containing two lines: the line from matexmatic's comment and \usepackage{wheelchart}; then add #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{mywheelchart} to your Org file.

Again, thank you NickD.
